How to concatenate XML field in different node, if a key field is common between them?
My source xml file has elements in this form:
<Employees>
<Employee>
<Name>ABC</Name>
<City>Delhi</Delhi>
</Employee>
<Employee>
<Name>ABC</Name>
<City>Mumbai</Delhi>
</Employee>
<Employee>
<Name>KBC</Name>
<City>Kolkata</Delhi>
</Employee>
</Employees>

I've used the following XSLT code
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <Employees> 
        <xsl:for-each-group select="row" group-starting-with="row[Name/text()]">
            <Employee>  
                <FIELD7>
                    <xsl:value-of select="City" separator="|"/>
                </FIELD7> 
            </Employee>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </Employees> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Here, if the employee's name is same then the XSLT will concatenate the city with pipe. My expected output.
<Employees>
<Employee>
<Name>ABC</Name>
<City>Delhi|Mumbai</Delhi>
</Employee>
<Employee>
<Name>KBC</Name>
<City>Kolkata</Delhi>
</Employee>
</Employees>


Why don't you post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

See also https://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Your code makes no sense. You cannot use xsl:for-each-group in XSLT 1.0. And there are no root or row elements in your input. Nor is there a FIELD7 element in the expected output. It looks like you just grabbed some random example to hide the fact that you are looking for someone to do your work for you. Voting to close this question.

You have tagged the question as XSLT 1.0 but in your attempt you use XSLT 2/3's for-each-group so assuming you are using an XSLT 3 processor like a current release of Saxon Java, Saxon JS or SaxonC or SaxonCS or .NET you would need code like
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Employees">
    <xsl:copy> 
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Employee" group-by="Name">
            <xsl:copy>  
                <xsl:apply-templates/> 
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Employee/City">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/City" separator="|"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Online fiddle using Saxon 12 HE.
